# Why table reference numbers are incorrect?

Tags: tables, ref

The code below shows in the caption "table 1", which is correct, but in the text reference, it shows "table 2". How can I fix that?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\section{Measurements}
\label{sec:measx}
Table \ref{tab:meas}
\begin{table}[ht]
\label{tab:meas}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
A   & B \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption {Measurements}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You need to put `\label` in or after `\caption`.

Comment: Moving `\label` to the line after `\caption` makes no difference. Moving `\label` inside `\caption{\label{} Measurements}` does not make any difference either. Removing the previous `\section` works. It seems to mixup `\section` and `\table` enumerations.

Comment: you have to compile two times until the label will be correct.

Comment: Yes, I am aware two compilations are needed. It does not work. Tried  both on overleaf.com| and cygwin latex. https://www.overleaf.com/18835735vkgdyqsjfwdk

Comment: I was moving below `\caption` the wrong label (the `\label{sec:measx}` one). It work, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too long for a comment. If I compile

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\section{Measurements}
\label{sec:measx}
Table \ref{tab:meas}
\begin{table}[ht]

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
A   & B \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption {Measurements\label{tab:meas}}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

on my TeXLive2018 distribution, I get

[image]

If you do not get that result, you have either not compiled twice or there is something really wrong with your TeX installation.

Answer (score 3):

you also got the same result as in  [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot)  answer with the following mwe (note, table label is after table caption):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\section{Description}
\section{Measurements}
\label{sec:measx}

Table \ref{tab:meas}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
A   & B \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption {Measurements}
\label{tab:meas} % <---
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

tested in overleaf:

[image]